# How to use django date based generic views

Tags: django, django-views, django-generic-views

I have been trying to django `date based generic views` but have not been successful. The documentation does not give an example, so I have not understood them well. This [tutorial](http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/use_url_patterns_and_views_in_django/#Being_Generic_is_Good) here shows how to use generic views for a model that has a `slug field`.

The documentation says

```
Either object_id or (slug and slug_field) is required.
```

But I have not understood how actually to do that. My models.py contains

```
class CompanyActivity(models.Model):
    company = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    desc = models.TextField()
    text = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    activity_type = models.CharField(max_length=600)
```

and my urls.py contains

```
info_dict = {
    'queryset': CompanyActivity.objects.all(),
    'date_field': 'date',
}

    urlpatterns+= patterns('django.views.generic.date_based',
        url(r'^activity/(?P<year>d{4})/(?P<object_id>\d+)/$','object_detail', dict(info_dict,object_id='id',template_name='activity/detail.html')),
    )
```

I know there is something wrong in the `urls.py` I do not know how to pass the object_id, what I intend to do is that I want to display the activity page for a particular year. And multiple activity pages can be there for the same company for the same year.

When I look for this page

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/activity/2011/1
```

It says not found. Please help

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, you seem to be looking at the information for `object_detail`. As the name implies, that's for the *detail* of a particular object (based on the date), so is not relevant to your problem which is how to get the list of activities for a particular year. Again not surprisingly, the function you're looking for is [`archive_year`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-date-based-archive-year):

```
urlpatterns+= patterns('django.views.generic.date_based',
    url(r'^activity/(?P<year>d{4})/$','archive_year',
        dict(info_dict, template_name='activity/detail.html')),
)
```

That said, you shouldn't really be using the old function-based views at all - they've been replaced by class-based ones, which is why they're only accessible via the link that says "Function-based generic views (Deprecated)". See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/class-based-views/) on the new style.

Comment: Actually I want to use both - a list based on year as well detail of a particular object whose url looks like this. However as you pointed out I will have a look at the class based generic views.